# Javafx Label doesn't display in the window

Tags: java, javafx, label

I'm making a small project- a program that switches off the computer after the set amount of minutes and this is where to problem starts.

Label myResponse doesn't display the text in the window, and I don't have a clue why. I searched through many programs and mine is not using this label any differently.

Besides, if I put a number in a text field and press enter I can't close the program using the "x" in the upper right corner.

I will be grateful for helping me to solve these problems. Thanks in advance.

Here is a code:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CompSwitchOff extends Application  {

Label myText;
Label myResponse;
Button btn= new Button ("press enter.");
TextField tf;
String s= "";
int i;

public static void main (String [] args){
    launch (args);
}

public void start (Stage myStage){

    myStage.setTitle("TIMER");
    FlowPane rootNode= new FlowPane(20,20);
    rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene myScene= new Scene (rootNode,230, 200);
    myStage.setScene(myScene);
    myText= new Label ("how many minutes to shut down the computer?: ");
    myResponse= new Label(); 
    tf= new TextField ();
    tf.setPrefColumnCount(10);
    tf.setPromptText("Enter time to count.");



    tf.setOnAction( (ae)-> {

        s= tf.getText();
        myResponse.setText("computer will switch off in "+ s+ " minuts.");
        i= Integer.parseInt(s)*60000;

        try{ Thread.sleep(i);}
        catch (InterruptedException ie){}

        Process process;
        try{
            process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
        }
        catch (IOException ie){

        }  
    }
    );
    btn.setOnAction((ae)->{
        s= tf.getText();
        myResponse.setText("computer will switch off in "+ s+ " minuts.");
        i= Integer.parseInt(s)*60000;

        try{ Thread.sleep(i);}
        catch (InterruptedException ie){}

        Process process;
        try{
            process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
        }
        catch (IOException ie){

        }  

    }
    );

    rootNode.getChildren().addAll(myText, tf, btn, myResponse);
    myStage.show();
    myStage.setOnHidden((eh)->{});              
}
}
```

Comment: Your `Thread.sleep()` method is blocking the UI. Search StackOverflow for other questions on how to run tasks in the background thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zephyr already pointed out, the `Thread.sleep()` method blocks your whole method from further execution. If you add some log statements you can see that the program stops after `Thread.sleep(i)`.
Although your label text is set before the `Thread.sleep(i)` the GUI redraw probably happens after that.

So in order to get it running you should add your `Thread.sleep(i)` into a new thread and where it cannot block your main (GUI) thread.

For example:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}).start();
```